# Configure a golang rest api app for https on azure

Tags: azure, go, https, ssl-certificate

Hi I am new to golang and azure. I have build a golang rest api app and locally I have run it as http with the following command locally:

`http.ListenAndServe(":4000", nil)`

In azure I need to use https, so that I am using:

`http.ListenAndServeTLS(":10443", cert.pem, key.crt, nil)`

In my local computer I have created a self signed certificate and can locate the cert and key files. But in azure how can I add self signed certificate and how can I pass these two parameters in ListenAndServeTLS function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean your application is running on a Windows Azure server?

Comment: @gcallea yes it is running on a Windows Azure server.

Comment: Ok. Another question, do you execute "locally" your application compiled executable providing cert.pem and key.crt on the same directory?

Comment: @gcallea no when running in local computer, I used it with http so I do not need .pem and .cert file as parameter in the http.ListenAndServe(:4000,nil), But to run in azure the domain name is with https and I need to use http.ListenAndServeTLS(), which require other two parameters for certificate file. I do not know where I can get those file. and how to provide the path.

Comment: @gcallea yes once I generated a self signed certificate on local computer. But it was not on the same drive. Therefore I gave the full path of those two files. and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just recreate your local environment on your Windows Azure server.
Supposing that locally you need the following files to execute your app:

```
appDir/
appDir/cert.pem
appDir/cert.key
appDir/appExecutable
```

You just have to move all these data on your server ( for example via **scp** ) and then execute the app on it paying attention on opening incoming traffic to port **10443** over your server

Comment: it worked for me to keep the certificate file on the same directory from where i am calling http,ListenAndServeTLS function. Thanks.